# Converting MS Oracle client to Oracle Data Provider - OracleException

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I'm converting a product from System.Data.OracleClient to Oracle.DataAccess.Client, and came across a question  Here's a snippet of some code:

```
try
{
    //some db code
}
catch (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException ex)
{
    if (ex.Code == 00904)
    {
        // log specific error
    }
}
```

The problem is, `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException` has no `Code` property.  It has a `Number` property.  Is this the same thing?  The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/OracleExceptionClass.htm#autoId6) say this about the property -

> This error number can be the topmost level of error generated by
>   Oracle and can be a provider-specific error number.

The `Code` property contained the ORA- error code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are the same thing. `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.Number` is the same info as `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Code`.